# iOS USB HID programming

Tags: ios, usb, device, gamekit, hid

I am trying to make some code regarding USB HID devices. I have found [an article](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1) about Bluetooth programming which uses [Game Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit).

Now I'm looking for some tutorial or maybe some code to work on connecting HID device via USB. Where should I look? Is `Game Kit` the right way? Is it difficult to implement communication between iOS and HID device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IOKit` for USB, but it's a private framework on iOS - so it depends if you want to deploy to the App Store.

Here is the [USB Intro for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html), I'm not sure if it's the same on iOS - but just to get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. But I plan to put my app into the AppStore. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I just found out that you can develop for external devices with [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). It's nicely described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1657/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010232). Also some technical info in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html).

But I don't really know what that means... ?

Comment: Yes, I know of it's existence - but I believe you have to pay license fees.