# Monotouch support on iOS Bluetooth HID

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, bluetooth, hid

I've been searching a lot for the monotouch support on bluetooth, specifically for Bluetooth HID support but have found none. Do we have it in Monotouch. sample code, discussion? 
or anything about the MonoTouch support on Bluetooth HID.. im working my way there..  It's monotouch so its for iOS but if u have experience for monodroid, u could as well give us some thought.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that Apple provides any public API for doing this.  MT provides access to the iOS API, so if iOS does not provide it then MT cannot do it either.

[iOS USB HID programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373453/ios-usb-hid-programming)

Comment: Isn't this link a  the one you have mentioned as a public API for the HID profile programmin?[link] https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EASession_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EASession